# integration by parts for unknown function

Tags: integration

It might be a bit of a stupid question, but well, I'm a bit confused. Ok so I want to integrate this by part:
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$$
I choose $u=f(x)$, $dv=g(x)dx$, so $v=\int g(x)dx$. That's where I am confused. What are the bounds when I use the formula $\int_a^b udv=uv|_a^b-\int_a^b vdu$? My reflex would be that my integral becomes:
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=\left(f(x)\int_a^xg(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime}\right)_a^b-\int_a^b\left(\int_a^xg(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)dx$$
Or:
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=f(b)\int_a^b g(x)dx-\int_a^b\left(\int_a^xg(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)dx$$
But I find that a bit weird that the term at the lower bound disappears. The thing is, I don't have an analytic expression for either functions, and don't have any data either. I'm just trying to get physical insight from my equations. It might seem like a weird thing to do, but I have my reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=f(x)$ and $dv = g(x)dx$. Then $du = f'(x)dx$ and
$$v = \int_a^x g(t)dt.$$
So,
\begin{align} \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx &= f(x) \Big( \int_a^x g(t)dt \Big) \bigg|_a^b - \int_a^b \Big( \int_a^x g(t)dt \Big) f'(x)dx \\
&= f(b) \int_a^b g(t)dt - \int_a^b \int_a^x f'(x)g(t)dtdx.
\end{align}